# LDAP User Authentication

Tags: python-3.x, security, ldap

To verify user credentials on LDAP Server, is bind the only way to do this ?. For Example: If a username and password doesn’t have access to LDAP but its contents are on LDAP, so we have to login with admin/other credentials and then check for the other users credentials. Is this a valid scenario ? I am currently working in Python with LDAP API.

Comment: Yes or give the user permission to read their entry's attributes.